# AG grid infinite scroll by making api call in React

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Does AgGrid supports infinte scroll, and hit API when the scroll reaches to the bottom to fetch the data and append it to the existing data in react.
Do we have the capability to implement virtualization, like loading the next 10 to 20 records in the browser memory and load it without causing any delay in rendering. And the api call hitting should continue during virtualization.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible,

in the grid ready method, AGGrid options

```
grid-ready="onGridReady"
```

you can set server side data source

```
async onGridReady({ api }) {
            this.api = api;
            const getRows = this.getRows.bind(this);
            api.setServerSideDatasource({ getRows });
        },
```

then your getRows does your data retrieval and you will need to handle and filtering or sorting too that gets set in the grid (this is true in my case anyway)

```
getRows(params) {
                const request = {
                    filterAndSortData: this.filterAndSortData
                };

                this.getData(request)
                    .then(({ data }) => {
                        params.successCallback(data, data.lastRow);
                    })
                    .catch(() => params.failCallback());
            },
```

your data may return back 100 records and then the data.lastRow will be the number of total records available for example 1000. so then as the user scrolls down it will fetch the next 100 rows

Comment: thanks for taking time to provide the solution. I have one question. Will the `getRows` trigger everytime once the scroll reaches the bottom?

Comment: yes it will, so the way mine works is when i scroll down it will call get rows and the grid show a loading overlay until the data is returned and ag-grid fills in the data on the ui. and your backend should handle only getting the X amount different records each time